# Can I change the icon of a Chrome app pinned to the start menu in Windows 10?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

The latest versions of the popular browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox) support creating a link to webpages as a "desktop app".

In Windows 10, when you pin such an app created through IE to the start page, the icon of the website gets used instead of the IE icon. When doing this with a link created through Chrome, this is not the case. The website icon shows up in the "All apps" list, and also when pinning it to the taskbar, but when pinning it to the start page the Chrome icon shows up. When checking the properties of the link, the icon is propperly set.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just ran across [this answer at TenForums](https://www.tenforums.com/browsers-email/29882-google-chrome-pinning-gmail-start-menu-after-1511-a.html#post511254) that seems to work. I'm curious to see how well it persists. The gist:

1. In the same folder as `chrome.exe` (in my case, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application`), there's a file called `chrome.VisualElementsManifest.xml`. Back it up if you like, then delete it.
2. *Then* change the icon of the Chrome app. (Specifically, open the Start Menu, **right-click** the  tile whose icon you wish to change, go to **More** > **Open Folder Location**. In the folder that comes up, **right-click** the app shortcut > **Properties** > **Shortcut** tab > **Change Icon...** button and set it appropriately.)

Worked for me just now with the Chrome apps Postman and Draw.io Desktop, using Chrome 59 on Windows 10 Enterprise Creator's Update (Version 10.0.15063).

---

*UPDATE: the icons are still set correctly on my machine 6 weeks later, through Windows updates and upgrading to Chrome 60.*

Comment: I don't have time to test this now, (and no longer care, since i started using Everything search, instead of the windows menu). If someone can confirm this works, and leave a comment, i can accept the answer.

Comment: This worked for me exactly as described.

Comment: For me, this answer worked, except I also had to unpin and repin to the start menu.

Comment: **chrome.VisualElementsManifest.xml** Removing this Item was the solution for me. Also I did it for several other applications and it worked flawlessly. Thanks!

Comment: What actually works for me nowadays: Create a Chrome shortcut via `Settings - More tools - Create shortcut` (open as window checked). The Chrome app with correct icon opens up. Right click on it's taskbar icon, click 'Pin to taskbar'. Icon disappears, default Chrome icon shows up instead. Right click, 'Unpin from taskbar', close the app. The app shortcut is also generated automatically on the desktop and I just drag this shortcut to the taskbar, and it stays lika that, with the correct icon (tested for more than a year, still OK).

Comment: @KristiánFilo: Nice! The original question was about the Start Menu, but the same general approach applies there now too: you can use Chrome's `Settings - More tools - Create shortcut`, then right-click the new shortcut on the Desktop and "Pin to Start".